# win32_processor.LoadPercentage null?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to get the current CPU load on my server by using

```
get-wmiobject win32_processor | select LoadPercentage
```

This works fine on my desktop and other servers, but it returns blank on this server.

The server is using Powershell v4.

Comment: Not near a server to test, but see if "Run as administrator" improves things.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to rebuild the performance counters with [lodctr /r](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490926.aspx). Please read and understand the documentation as this will reset all performance counters. I would strongly recommend backing up your settings with lodctr /s:*[filename]* first.